# I'm trying to make a secure password generating program. Well, I was debugging the Index Error that I get when I ran this incomplete program

Tags: python

I seem to have run into wall here. It keeps showing an Index Error at line "unordered_letter[letter] = random.choice(letters[nr_letters - 1])". My inexperienced eyes are unable to catch the issue so kindly help with the same. Thanks in advance!

```
import random

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
           'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
           'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters = int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n"))
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))

unordered_letter = []

for letter in range(0, nr_letters):
    unordered_letter[letter] = random.choice(letters[nr_letters - 1])
print(unordered_letter)
```

Comment: Try `unordered_letter.append(random.choice(letters[nr_letters - 1]))` instead.

Comment: Or this: `for letter in range(nr_letters):
    unordered_letter.append(random.choice(letters))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
for letter in range(0, nr_letters):
    unordered_letter[letter] = random.choice(letters[nr_letters - 1])
```

To this:

```
for letter in range(0, nr_letters):
    unordered_letter.append(random.choice(letters))
```

Change #1:

Use the `.append()` function. Your original code produces an error since you are trying to set a value to a nonexistent index since your array is empty.

Change #2:

Change  `random.choice(letters[nr_letters - 1])` to  `random.choice(letters)` if you want to produce a variety of letters rather than one singular letter. Your original code will only append the `nr_letters - 1`th element of `letters`, while this new code will choose random elements from `letters`.

Use the same process for symbols and numbers.

Comment: Earlier I made a program to calculate highest marks in a class and in that program my tutor assigned values to an empty list by assigning value to each index of the empty list as for loop progressed.

Comment: @Sachit was the list empty like [] or did it have dummy values like [0]?

Comment: do you have sample code that shows what you are talking about

Comment: for score in student_score: student_scores[score] = int(student_score[score])print(student_scores) I get that this converts the string input to int values but the code does manages to assign the values to a list without prompting an index error.

Comment: What's `student_score` vs `student_scores`? Is `student_score` originally just set to `[]`?

Comment: It was a typo, there's only "student_scores". He takes the values from user and splits the input and rest I've written above.

Comment: The values in `student_scores` already exist - that is that for every index, an element already exists there, so we can modify that value. In the original problem, we are starting with an empty list with no defined values, so we need to use the `.append()` method since there is no value to "modify"

Comment: I got it. Silly me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is as already stated to use `append` but you could simplify your code a lot by using the stdlib `string` and `random.sample`

```
unordered_letters = random.sample(string.ascii_letters, nr_letters)
```